# Proving a sequence converges almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of random variables in a probability space such that $E(X_n)< 2^{-n}$. Show that $X_n \rightarrow 0$ almost surely as $n\to \infty$

This is a problem I am not so sure on. I have a lot of convergence theorems but not so sure which to use here (if any). I was thinking maybe Markovs inequality since it had an expectation in it, but this wouldn't help me show the almost surely part.

I am just practicing for my exams so I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me solve the problem. Unfortunately this exercise does not give me solution with it.

Comment: Hint : You can combine Markov inequality and the Borel–Cantelli lemma to prove it.

Comment: Are the $X_i$-s non-negative? Because for all we know they could all be the constant $-1$ function.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_n$ are non-negative then $$E(\sum_nX_n)=\sum_n E(X_n)<+\infty$$

So $\sum_nX_n<+\infty$ a.e

Thus $X_n \to 0$ a.e

If you $X_n$ are negative for infinitely $n's$ then the statement is not true.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how can I do it with Markovs and Borel Cantelli, like P. Quinton said?

Comment: if $X_n$ are negative then you cannot prove since it is not correct..for non negative $X_n$ you do not need Borel canteli..its just a little bit overkill

Comment: How'd you go from the sum being finite to $X_n$ going to zero? This makes sense intuitively but how would I show it is true?

Comment: @georoberto55  Let $S$ be the set of values on which the sum conveeges...fix $x \in S$..then $\sum_nX_n(x)<\infty$ thus $X_n(x) \to 0$(since $x$ is fixed then $X_n(x)$ is a sequence of numbers) since if a sum of a sequence of numbers converges then the sequence goes to zero.

Comment: Why is taking the summation out here justified? Because isn't $\{X_{n}\}$ a sequence ?

Comment: @georoberto55  if $X_n$ are non negative,the the interchange is by dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick reply. I actually typo'd the question, and it should have been $E(|X_{n}|)$ instead of $E(X_{n})$ (which probably explains why you needed non-negativity). Is the proof the exact same?

Comment: Yes it is exaxtly the same

Comment: $E(\sum_{n} |X_{n}|) \implies \sum_{n} E|X_{n}| < \infty \implies \sum_{n} |X_{n}| < \infty \text{  a.e. } \implies X_{n} \to 0 \text{ a. e.} $

Comment: One last question. How did you get from $\sum_{n} E(X_{n}) < \infty$ to $\sum_{n} X_{n} < \infty$  a.e.? This makes sense to me intuitively, but I'm studying for exam. So if there's some result name I can cite, it would be helpful

Comment: @georoberto55 In fact $\sum_nE(|X_n|) \Longrightarrow E(\sum_n|X_n|)<+\infty$ so by markov's inequality you can prove that $\sum_n|X_n|<+\infty$ a.s