# Prove a sequence converges almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of random variables on a
>   probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$  such that $E(|X_{n}|)
>  \leq 2^{-n}$. Prove that $X_{n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\to\infty$

This is a follow up to a question I asked earlier here: [Proving a sequence converges almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393309/proving-a-sequence-converges-almost-surely)

Can somebody please explain to me how I can solve this problem using Borel-Cantelli Lemma and/or Markov's Inequality and/or Monotone Convergence? Note that the following question is slightly different than the one I asked in the earlier question (there are absolute values now). I'm trying to understand different ways to solve problems as I study for exams, but this problem has been giving me more trouble than usual.

I would really appreciate some help with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(|X_n| >2^{-n/2}) \leq 2^{n/2}|EX_n|\leq 2^{-n/2}$ so $\sum P(|X_n| >2^{-n/2}) <\infty$. By Borel Cantelli Lemma this shows that $X_n \to 0$ almost surely.

Borel Cantelli Lemma tells you that with probability $1$ we have $|X_n| \leq 2^{-n/2}$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. This implies that $X_n \to $ almost surely.

Comment: How does this show $X_{n}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely by Borel Cantelli ? I know what the first and second Borel Cantelli Lemma say, but I'm not able to make the jump between this. I know the hypothesis is satisfied because we have $P(A) < \infty$, so I think that means $P(\limsup_{n\to\infty} E_n) = 0$

Comment: @georoberto55 See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

For any $\varepsilon > 0$, 
$$\eqalign{\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n > N} \{|X_n|\ge\varepsilon\}\right)
&\le \sum_{n > N} \mathbb P\left(\{|X_n| \ge \varepsilon\}\right)
\cr&\le \varepsilon^{-1} \sum_{n > N} \mathbb E[X_n]\cr &\le \varepsilon^{-1} 2^{-N}\cr
&\to 0\ \text{as }N \to \infty }$$
Thus $\mathbb P(\limsup_{n \to \infty} |X_n| \ge \varepsilon) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first inequality is Boole's inequality. The second inequality comes from the hypothesis. But how does the third inequality come? And can $N$ just be an arbitrary index?

Comment: $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty 2^{-n} = 2^{-N}$.